# Method 'setTag' with Objective-C selector 'setTag:' conflicts with setter for 'tag' from superclass 'UIView' with the same Objective-C selector

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I am converting my Objective-C code into Swift.
I have done all required things like: In Bridging-header imported the “DCclass.h" etc. Things work fine but while setting tag I am facing an issue, searched for this on Google but did not get a solution. Thanks in Advance.

***Current Objective-C code:***

**The .h file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import “DCclass.h”

@interface LPFPickerCell : UITableViewCell <UITableViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>

- (void)setDelegate:(id) delegate;
- (void)setMyMutableArray:(NSMutableArray *) mutArray;
- (void)setSelectedData:(NSString *) selectedString

@end
```

**The .m file:**

```
#import “DCclass.h”
@interface LPFPickerCell ()
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
@end
@implementation LPFPickerCell

- (void)setTag:(NSInteger)tag
{
    self.m_Tag = tag;
}
- (void)setSelectedData:(NSString *) selectedString
{    
    int i = 0;
    for (DCclass *dc in self.myMutableArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"DCclass.empName = %@",dc.empName);
    }
}
@end
```

***Converted Swift Code:***

```
class LPFPickerCell {

    var myMutableArray = [AnyHashable]()
    var m_Tag: Int = 0

    func setTag(_ tag: Int) {   /// This line is showing error same as Question post title described above.
        m_Tag = tag
    }

    func setSelectedData(_ selectedString: String?) {
        let i: Int = 0
        for dc: DCclass in myMutableArray {
        print("DCclass.empName = \(dc.empName)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just change the name of the method in the swift code, since you have conflicts with the name set tag from UIView

Comment: Yes that helped but actually if i dont want to change the method name then any othere way is there? actually if i am changing this then at many places i have to change this while its call. See if any solution else its ok this changing method name works... but a lot of work for me...

Comment: I don't think so... Just use replacing all over your project to do your replacing faster... But you can't change superclass declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of your method, it says that an existing method that has the name `setTag` already exist for the `UIView` swift class.

Just change `setTag` to something like `setCellId` or what you want.

Comment: Yes that helped but actually if i dont want to change the method name then any othere way is there? actually if i am changing this then at many places i have to change this while its call. See if any solution else its ok this changing method name works... but a lot of work for me...